# Open permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created a custom permission level and have only set it so that people can only open and view files. The issue is that I have been able to open them, edit, and save them. Then when I log out and log back in under my admin account it says that I edited the document a few minutes ago.

I'm trying to make it so that a user can see the documents in word or excel online and be able to download them. However I don't want them to be able to edit the documents. I've done some research and what I've done should be able to accomplish this but it does not for some reason. Any suggestions?

**Update**

I actually changed it so that they have "View Only" permissions but there is no option to download. I went to the Advanced Library options and enabled offline downloading but there is still no option to download. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that your non admin account doesn't have site collection admin rights or permissions via another group. What permissions have you selected for your custom permission level?

Comment: @SimonDoy I have checked and that user is part of one group that have limited access to the list. I have their subsite running a content query for that library. They can see the documents that are listed and they can click on them to open them up in word online. The issue is that there is an option for "Open in Word" and when they open it, if they make any changes and hit save it uploads the new version to SP. The group itself is given "test" permissions which includes "View Items", "open items", "view pages", and "Open" for the site permissions.

Comment: @SimonDoy I actually changed it so that they have "View Only" permissions but there is no option to download. I went to the Advanced Library options and enabled offline downloading but there is still no option to download. Any help would be appreciated!